# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in Swing

Tags: java

I am doing a simple project in java swing, just to make time pass.
When I try to start the application, it gives me this error:

```
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\Java\bin\awt.dll: Routine di inizializzazione della libreria di collegamento dinamico (DLL) non riuscita
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:310)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2416)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1380)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1378)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1377)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1410)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:622)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

Here's the code (I got 3 classes):

this is the class page:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Page extends JFrame {
    Header header = new Header();
    public Page(){
        super("FW Ultra");
        this.setSize(1000, 700);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        this.add(header);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

this is the class header:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Header extends JPanel {
    public Header(){
        super();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JLabel("FVU | Film Viewer Ultra"),  BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(new JLabel("Version 1.0"),  BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```

and this is the main

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Page p = new Page();
    }
}
```

PLZ help mee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a couple of changes to your code and came up with this GUI.  I reduced the size of the GUI by half so it would fit better in the answer.

[image: FW Ultra GUI]

I changed some of the code in all three of your classes.  I made your classes inner classes so I could post them as one block.  You should separate them.

I started your Swing GUI with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FileViewerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FileViewerMain().new Page();
            }
        });
    }
    
    public class Page extends JFrame {
        Header header = new Header();
        public Page(){
            super("FW Ultra");
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.add(new Header(), BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
            this.setSize(500, 350);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    
    public class Header extends JPanel {
        public Header(){
            super();
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JLabel("FVU | Film Viewer Ultra"),  BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(new JLabel("Version 1.0"),  BorderLayout.EAST);
        }
    }

}
```